# grub rescue in formating a os in dual boot

Tags: grub2

my system is dual booted with Ubuntu 14.04 and kubuntu 14 being vexed with Ubuntu i formatted the disk containing Ubuntu  a error like grub rescue is been displayed to access kubuntu what should i do please help solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Live boot from your Ubuntu DVD/Pendrive.
2. Click on 'Try Ubuntu'
3. Open Terminal and enter the command `sudo fdisk -l`. This will list your partitions in the system. Find the partition that contains your kubuntu. It will be something like

`/dev/sda7       614408192  3890325503  1637958656   83  Linux`

Make a note of the **`dev/sda7`** (this will be different for you). I will be using it as **`/dev/sdXY`** from now on
4. Enter the commands:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/kubuntu
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/kubuntu
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/kubuntu/boot /dev/sdXY
(For me, it would be sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/kubuntu/boot /dev/sda7)
```

Now reboot the system. You will have your grub back and it will boot into kubuntu.

**Note:** If you have other OSs installed in your system, then you can run `sudo update-grub` from your kubuntu to generate a grub configuration to recognize the installed OSs in your system